# images is not showing in react-js

Tags: reactjs, image, directory, components

I want to create a card slider in react-js for that I have to create an object to store the images and title and other paragraph but after creating all these things only images are not visible may be there is a problem while importing it, i cannot resolve it please help me

**Here is my code:**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import React, { flexbox, card } from "react";
import Logo from "../../assets/images/logo1.png";
import "./index.scss";
import Loader from "react-loaders";

const Portfolio = () => {
  const [letterClass, setLetterClass] = useState("text-animate");

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return setLetterClass("text-animate-hover");
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  //creating project cards
  const data = [
    { name: Ritu, img: "../../../assets/images/issue.jpg", review: Protyusha },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container portfolio-page">
        <div className="text">
          <h1>
            <AnimatedLetters
              letterClass={letterClass}
              strArray={[
                "P",
                "",
                "r",
                "",
                "o",
                " ",
                "j",
                "",
                "e",
                " ",
                "c ",
                " ",
                "t",
              ]}
              idx={15}
            />
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* <Cards/> */}

      <div className="w-3/4 m-auto">
        <div className="mt-20">
          {data.map((d) => (
            <div>
              <div>
                <img src={d.img} alt="" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>{d.name}</p>
                <p>{d.review}</p>
                <button>Read more</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>

      <Loader type="pacman" />
    </>
  );
};

export default Portfolio;
```

This the code of portfolio folder inside the component folder , inside data object there are image but i cannot get the image after rendering the page (**styling is not done )

Comment: Might be easier to answer this one if you put all the code in the same code formatting box. Right now its hard to read it.

Comment: Where are you putting your assets folder ? Is it in public folder ?

Comment: I am putting this assets folder inside src  folder the image is inside assets folder